# Remove GO Keyboard language notification icon

Tags: notification-icons

I am using the latest version of GO Keyboard from the Play Store on a Nexus 5.

Whenever the keyboard is active, there is a notification icon on the right side that says the language selected, in my case 'En' over a green leaf icon.

Is there any way to remove this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Long press on the notification and check 'hide app's notification icon'.

Comment: That means I won't get any notifications from the app, which should be a last resort. Also, I just tried that, and it did not prevent the notification icon.

Comment: And if you do what I said now that I edited my answer? I never did that so I don't know if you will not receive notifications but it does take care of the icon.

Comment: It still doesn't get rid of it. I can't long press on it. It is on the right side of the notification area, not the left side if that makes a difference.